# gensim: KeyError: "word 'quick' not in vocabulary"

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec, gensim

I am running the below code, but gensim word2vec is throwing a word not in vocabulary error. Can you let me know the solution?

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

sentences = [["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"], 
         ["The sun is shining bright"]]

from gensim.models import word2vec
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, iter=10, min_count=1, size=300, workers=4)

print(model['quick'])
```

Output:

```
KeyError: "word 'quick' not in vocabulary"
```

But If I use this

```
print(model['The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'])
```

it prints a list

```
[  1.60348183e-03  -9.17983416e-04  -8.30831763e-04   9.46367683e-04
```

Answer (score 6):

Sentence should be list of tokens, i.e.

change

```
sentences = [["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"], 
             ["The sun is shining bright"]]
```

to

```
sentences = ["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".split(), 
             "The sun is shining bright".split()]
```

After it - all works correctly

```
print(model['quick'])
```

> [  1.44969602e-03   1.22959237e-03  -6.55176700e-04  -4.09452856e-04
>      8.06640834e-04   1.05476158e-03  -9.90176341e-04 ...